# sparkSQL Map column in group by clause

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am migrating a query from Hive to SparkSQL, but, running into one issue with Map column.

My query is

```
spark.sql(select col1,col2,my_map,count(*) from table group by col1,col2,my_map)
```

The error I get is

```
`my_map` cannot be used as a grouping expression because its data type map<string,string> is not an orderable data type.;
```

The keys in my_map always vary. I tried using deprecated HiveContext, but, that didn't help. Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: grouping by a map seems a rather delicate operation. Are you sure you really want to do this? 

Anyway, you can think about normalizing the map before doing this query (especially if you expect only a few keys), otherwise you should transform it back and forth to another format that can be easily handled by sql.

Comment: @Chobeat I have been doing it in Hive up until now. Any idea how I could transform it back and forth to another format ?

Comment: a list of tuples may be an option, I believe it should work. But be careful, this is really close to a dirty work around

Comment: @Chobeat How do I convert a Map column from to a list of tuples and convert it back to map?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error response. You need to make my_map into an orderable data type! :)